# Find index of returned list result C#

Tags: c#, string, list, indexing, indexof

How do you find the index of an entry within a list. My code below.

`listFrom` and `listTo` contain entries of strings.

I am getting the error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

```
List<string> listFrom = new List<string>(); //Contains a list of strings
List<string> listTo = new List<string>(); //Contains a list of strings

List<string> lineStart = listFrom.Except(listTo).ToList(); //Will always return a single value
List<string> lineEnd = listTo.Except(listFrom).ToList(); //Will always return a single value

int startLineIndex = listFrom.IndexOf(lineStart);            //Error on this line
Console.WriteLine("Index of Start: " + startLineIndex);
```

Comment: Your lists are all empty. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you not understand about that compile time error? That method takes a `string` as parameter, you are passing in a `List<string>`.

Comment: `listFrom.IndexOf` expects a `string` you are passing a `List<string>` - the error message is really clear on this

Comment: You are passing a list of strings into method that expects a string.

Comment: `IndexOf()` Expects a single string (or whatever type your list is).  You are passing it a `List<string>`, not a `string`.  Can you not see why thats a problem?  How can you expect the method to find a single index of an item in a list, when you are passing it a completely different type than what the list contains?

Comment: @maccettura Yes I see this. But how would I go about converting this line `List<string> lineStart = listFrom.Except(listTo).ToList();` into a string?

Comment: @Stefan I have no idea what you are trying to do.  `Except()` gives you a collection of the difference between two lists.  If you are sure that there will only ever be _one_ item in the resulting collection, dont call `ToList()`, call `SingleOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefault()` depending on your need.  Make sure you lookup the difference between those.

Comment: @maccettura Thank you. `SingleOrDefault()` does what I want. Correct there will always be one item returned. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, it cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.List'` to `'string'`. However I never knew the function `SingleOrDefult()` existed.

`All credit to @maccettura even though he didn't know what I was trying to do! xD`

Code change below for the answer:

```
List<string> listFrom = new List<string>(); //Contains a list of strings
List<string> listTo = new List<string>(); //Contains a list of strings

string lineStart = listFrom.Except(listTo).SingleOrDefault();
string lineEnd = listFrom.Except(listTo).SingleOrDefault();

int startLineIndex = listFrom.IndexOf(lineStart);            //Error on this line
Console.WriteLine("Index of Start: " + startLineIndex);
```

Comment: Make sure you are aware of what `SingleOrDefault()` does, if for some reason you have more than one items as a result, it _will_ throw an exception.  [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you call `listFrom.IndexOf(lineStart);` it's expecting a String. lineStart in your code is defined as a List of Strings so you would either need to call on a specific value inside the list, or change lineStart to a string.

Comment: if the OP changed `lineStart` to a string the code would not compile.  There would be more that needed to be done